# What layer handle transaction and session hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm developing a Java web application in layer  using patters such as DAO, MVC and some frameworks such as Hibernate.
My question is What is the best way to manage transaction and session, if I will use the DAO pattern to access my database?
I am a college student and my teachers are mutually exclusive views on this topic. Regards

[image]

Comment: I think "persistencia" is your so-called "service" layer (I speak Spanish). At that level is where most applications usually manage transactions since it's where eventually different operations (potentially including more than one database call) might occur

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ  I did not call service , because I'm not developing a web service, the service layer I Replace by webapp , thanks for observation ! sorry for my bad english ;)

Comment: Oh, what I meant for "service" is the place where you put your business logic...but coming to the question you can use Hibernate or Spring for that matter

Comment: ahhh ok, you are recommending me forget dao pattern ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best is using transaction management by Spring. The `@Transactional` annotation to use transactions. The session factory use `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. All bean are managed by spring so you have no worries.

Comment: The problem is that I'm very new in spring. I do not understand the concept when performing a commit or rollback , if physical or logical , thanks for your edition , I am Argentine and English is very bad

Comment: You'd better consult Spring documentation for description and explanation of Transaction management with Spring. I can only add that you don't have to use any commit or rollback if you use `@Transactional`.